# Reading azure datalake gen2 file from pyspark in local

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, azure-data-lake

I am trying to read a file located in Azure Datalake Gen2 from my local spark (version spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2) using pyspark script.
Script is the following

```py
import dbutils as dbutils
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

file = "abfs://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/test-file-system/dummy.txt"
key = "key"
appName = "DataExtract"
master = "local[*]"
sparkConf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) \
    .set("fs.azure.myaccount.key.myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net", key)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.text(file)
df.show()
```

The error I have is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = spark.read.text(file)
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 389, in text
    return self._df(self._jreader.text(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(paths)))
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\apps\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.text.
: abfs://myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/test-file-system/dummy.txt has invalid authority.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.authorityParts(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.<init>(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.initialize(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:843)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Has anyone similar error? I don't know if the error is some configuration missing in the code or in my pc or some configuration in azure account for datalake.
Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.
file route must be

```
file="abfss://<<container>>@<<storageaccount>>.dfs.core.windows.net/<<topfolder>>/<<subfolder>>/file"
```

I found the solution in
https://deep.data.blog/2019/07/12/diy-apache-spark-and-adls-gen-2-support/

And check you have all necessary .jar installed.